# Si tengo una pregunta, pero investigué y encontré la respuesta, puedo aun preguntarla aqui esperando que alguien la responda?

Tags: discusión

El tema no lo conocía, pero una búsqueda rápida en google dio una respuesta precisa. ¿Debería publicar la pregunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nada te impide preguntar.

Si la respuesta es fácil de encontrar, es posible que la gente no vote tu pregunta, o incluso vote negativo alegando que la pregunta no muestra esfuerzo previo.

También podrías publicar una respuesta a tu propia pregunta, lo que puede aportar contenido interesante al sito que de otra manera no habría llegado al sito (y puedes publicar esta respuesta como *[community wiki](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)* o no a tu elección). Puede ser que otros usuarios amplíen con otras respuestas propias, enriqueciendo el contenido.

En definitiva, no está prohibido, y eres tú quien debe juzgar si merece o no publicarse/preguntarse de todas formas o no. **Tú eres el último y principal responsable del contenido que tú como usuario aportas al sitio**.

En cualquier caso, habría que evitar ciertas cosas, como publicar por publicar, publicar post que son simples "copia y pega" de otros sitios (nuestros posts deben explicar, en lugar de decir "estas son las normas"), publicar cosas que no aporten valor real, "importar" sitios enteros en este,  etc.

Comment: It's always a possibility to state in your question that you're aware that an answer is easily to find (and thus you're answering it yourself) but that you still considered it an *interesting question* that has not yet been asked, much less covered, on StackExchange. In the interest of Spanish.SE any good question is valuable; and this should prevent some (not all) from downvoting.